# Java: 1-click Mac executable including VM arguments

Tags: java, macos, executable-jar

I am building a small Java program for a Mac user who is an absolute novice when it comes to computing. Therefore, I would like to give him one file to execute, perhaps via a script. Before, I just gave the .jar file, which would run perfectly, but now I have to add VM arguments (max heap space). Unfortunately, I'm not well acquianted with OSX. So far, I was able to give the .jar and a .command file containing the text

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar -ms128m -mx512m -jar file.jar
```

However, this gives the message 'The file could not be executed because you do not have appropriate access privileges'. One solution is to use sudo in the console, but I'm afraid this is too complex. Therefore my question:

- can I make a .command or other script run a java .jar file without going to the console?
- or, can I wrap the .jar file in some kind of Mac executable, including VM arguments? I found a similar solution (Launch4j) for windows.
- or, is there maybe another way to give a simple mail-downloadable, executable that runs a java program, but without installing any other programs?

edit: I do not have unlimited access to a Mac, so I would need a solution that does not require a Mac at each update of the .jar file.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The file is executable (755) in linux, does this transfer to mac? I'm afraid I can't ask the user to do a chmod (a console is already too difficult to explain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you have a Mac you can try out the [Jar Bundler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Jar_Bundler/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000884). It come with XCode or perhaps you can find it here https://developer.apple.com/downloads. With this app you can make a 1 Click Mac Executable.
2. I don't know if it's possible with a Windows Eclipse version. Go to the Main-Class open the context menu and start the Export dialog. Search for **Mac OS X application bundle** and follow the steps.
3. Create an extra Java "starter" class which starts itself again. You can call with `ProcessBuilder` another jar like this `java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar app.jar`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have one. I could borrow one for development purposes for a short time, but I would like to find a method that I can also send updates (i.e. a new .jar file). Getting my hands on a mac every time the program changes is unfortunately not possible.

Comment: I see - that could be a problem. Added another way to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'm on linux, but it's not in my export-other. This doens't seem to be a plugin when searching for it, just standard functionality when running eclipse on mac, or am I wrong? Can I install this application bundle export as a eclipse plugin?

Comment: Looks like it's only available to Eclipse for Mac OS. Added another way. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Mac executable quite easily. You should create a directory with an extension .app and put your files there. It should contain a subdirectory called Contents where you should put a file named Info.plist where you can specify JVM parameter and a lot of other stuff. As an example, you can use the IntelliJ Community Edition package.

Comment: Just to be sure: - create a folder called program.app, create a subfolder Contents, containing a file info.plist with <key>Java</key><dict><key>VMOptions<string>-Xmx512m</string></key></dict>, add the .jar in the Contents folder and then? Do I need to add any other keys? What do you do to launch the program?

Comment: I would copy-paste info.plist from IntelliJ and replace only parts which are specific to your program. As a result of this you will have an application package which you can just click and run (like any other Mac application).